# How to call a closure that is a class variable?

Tags: php, lambda, closures, anonymous-function

```
class MyClass {
  var $lambda;
  function __construct() {
    $this->lambda = function() {echo 'hello world';};
    // no errors here, so I assume that this is legal
  }
}

$myInstance = new MyClass();
$myInstance->lambda();
//Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::lambda()
```

So what is the correct syntax for reaching class variables ?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

In PHP, methods and properties are in a separate namespace (you can have a method and a property with the same name), and whether you are accessing a property or a method depends of the syntax you are using to do so.

`$expr->something()` is a method call, so PHP will search `something` in the class' list of methods.

`$expr->something` is a property fetch, so PHP will search `something` in the class' list of properties.

`$myInstance->lambda();` is parsed as a method call, so PHP searches for a method named `lambda` in your class, but there is no such method (hence the *Call to undefined method* error).

So you have to use the *fetch property* syntax to fetch the lambda, and then call it.

- Since PHP 7.0, you can do this with `($obj->lambda)()`:

  ```
  ($obj->lambda)();
  ```

  The parentheses make sure that PHP parses `($obj->lambda)` as *fetch the property named lambda*. Then, `()` calls the result of fetching the property.
- or you can do this with `->lambda->__invoke()`:

  ```
  $myInstance = new MyClass();
  $myInstance->lambda->__invoke();
  ```

  [`__invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) is one of [PHP's magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). When an object implements this method, it becomes invokable: it can be called using the `$var()` syntax. Anonymous functions are instances of [`Closure`](http://www.php.net/Closure), which implements `__invoke`.
- Or assign it to a local variable:

  ```
  $lambda = $myInstance->lambda;
  $lambda();
  ```
- Or call it using call_user_func:

  ```
  call_user_func($myInstance->lambda);
  ```

  [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) can call any [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), including anonymous functions.
- Alternatively, if this is a common pattern in your code, you can setup a `__call` method to forward calls to your lambda:

  ```
  class MyClass
  {
      private $lambda;

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->lambda = function() {
              echo "Hello world!\n";
          };
      }

      public function __call($name, $args)
      {
          return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
      }
  }
  ```

  Now this works:

  ```
  $myInstance = new MyClass();
  $myInstance->lambda();
  ```

  Since PHP 5.4 you can even do that in a trait:

  ```
  trait LambdasAsMethods
  {
      public function __call($name, $args)
      {
          return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
      }
  }

  class MyClass
  {
      use LambdasAsMethods;

      private $lambda;

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->lambda = function() {
              echo "Hello World!\n";
          };
      }
  }

  $myInstance = new MyClass();
  $myInstance->lambda();
  ```

Comment: Nice, although it would be nice to see `__invoke/()` vs. `call_user_func` notes.

Comment: you can use traits for nearly everything, it's not a class, just a loosely pack of methods and props

Comment: This is not standing up: _$myInstance->lambda(); is parsed as a method call, so PHP searches for a method named lambda in your class, but there is no such method (hence the Call to undefined method error).._. Calling `self::$my_closure()` also doesn't work. While it's pretty clear that I'm calling a property.

Comment: God, do I hate PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can also call your lambda function without change something in your class, using ReflectionFunction.

```
$myInstance = new MyClass();
$lambda = new ReflectionFunction($myInstance->lambda);
$lambda->invoke();
```

or if you have to pass arguments then

```
$args = array('arg'=>'value');
$lambda->invokeArgs($args);
```

Comment: This isn't the shortest, nor the most efficient way of going about it.