# How to save a PHP closure(lambda function) into $this->var and call it later from another method of the same class?

Tags: php, lambda, closures

I have a class

```
class SomeClass {
  private $someVar;

  public function Init($func) {
    $this->someVar = $func;
  }

  public function DoSomething() {
    $this->someVar("asdasdasd");
  }
}

$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->Init(function ($param){var_dump($param);});
$obj->DoSomething();
```

When I call the method DoSomething, I get an error that `SomeClass::someVar()` is undefined method. But when I use the debugger, I see that it is a closure object. If I save the function into a local variable (`$someVar` without `$this`) and call it in the `Init()` function, it works just fine. But I don't want to call the function there. I want to call it later.

Even if I save it into `$this->someVar` and call it in the same scope it does not work.

Comment: [already solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067536/how-to-call-a-closure-that-is-a-class-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should simply try this :

```
public function DoSomething()
{
  $tmpVar = $this->someVar;
  $tmpVar("asdasdasd");
}
```

or, if you prefer, this :

```
public function DoSomething()
{
  call_user_func($this->someVar, "asdasdasd");
}
```

Comment: call_user_func works slowly. 1 variant will work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/P5gEiN

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function DoSomething()
{
    call_user_func( $this->someVar, 'test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have other options: [How to call a closure that is a class variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067536/how-to-call-a-closure-that-is-a-class-variable)

Basically:

- 1. Force the call to the [`__invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) magic method:

     $myInstance = new MyClass();
     $myInstance->lambda->__invoke();
- Or 2. Capture the method call:

  ```
  class MyClass
  {
      private $lambda;

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->lambda = function() {
              echo "Hello world!\n";
          };
      }

      public function __call($name, $args)
      {
          return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
      }
  }
  ```