# Declaring closure to class attribute in PHP

Tags: php, object, functional-programming, closures

Its strange, i can do

```
<?php

    $foo = function($a){
        return $a;
    };

var_dump($foo(123));
```

But in the scope of a classe if a do:

```
<?php

    class Totalizer{

        public $count;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->count = function($product){
                return  $product;
            };
        }

    }

    $foo = new Totalizer;
    var_dump($foo->count(123));
```

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Totalizer::count()**

My question is how can i do the same as the first snippet but in class scope?

ps: PHP 5.5

Comment: by defining a class method...

Comment: Detail explanation is done in below page

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067536/how-to-call-a-closure-that-is-a-class-variable

Comment: i don't want to define a class method, i want to define a closure to a attribute something dynamic

Comment: that's what methods are for.

Comment: user3911414 this link has the answer, thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Currently doesn't allow directly calling a function stored as an object property.

It allows properties and methods of an object to have the same name actually.

One [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535383/301457) to this issue is from another, almost identical question

```
class Totalizer
{
    public $count;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->count = function ($product) {
            return  $product;
        };
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (is_callable(array($this, $method))) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
        } else {
            // else throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HI this can be done by using __call magic method it will byepass the fetal error The

__call method invoked when we try to access some undefined method, I think

it may helpful to you.......

class Totalizer
{

public $count;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->count = function ($product) {
        return  $product;
    };
}

public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if ($method=="count") {

    } else {
        echo "Error ! method not foound!";
    }
}
```

}

$foo = new Totalizer;
var_dump($foo->count(123));

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but since PHP 7, you can do this (parenthesis are important):

```
var_dump(($foo->count)(123));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    class Totalizer{

        public function __construct(){
        }

        public function product( $count ) {
            if( is_int( $count ) )
                return $count;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }

$foo = new Totalizer;
var_dump($foo->product(123));
```